# My glossary is not displayed on screen

Tags: glossaries, overleaf, acronyms, report

I have the complete project divided into different files, the principal file code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{report}
\usepackage{tfg/mi_estilo}

\makeglossaries
%-------------------------------------------
\input{tfg/glossary.tex}
\begin{document}
    %---------------------------------------
    \input{tfg/1_portada}
    %---------------------------------------
    \input{tfg/encabezado}
    %---------------------------------------
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage
    \printglossary
    \clearpage
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
    \clearpage
    %---------------------------------------
    \input{tfg/2_memoria}
    \printbibliography
    \input{tfg/3_anexos}
    %---------------------------------------

\end{document}
```

I have one file called glossary.tex where I write the codes for the words I want to appear in the glossary. I have follow the guide for overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries,
but when I compile, after mention the words in the text with the command \gls or \Gls, the glossary don't appear in my project.

Comment: It's hard to say without a complete example code (we don't know the contents of tfg/glossary.tex, tfg/1_portada, etc.), but one common cause of this on Overleaf is if your main .tex file is inside a folder in your project structure. Is your main file inside a folder in the project's file tree? If so, does moving it up to the top level (not inside any folders) allow the glossary to be properly processed?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. That was exactly where I had the problem. I had a general folder where I had put all the documents, when I took them all out of the folder, I no longer had any problem.